# Apt-get cannot find version firefox=41.0+build3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

Tags: apt, firefox

In another box I have firefox 41.0+build3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 installed:

```
 apt-cache policy firefox
firefox:
  Installed: 41.0+build3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
```

I'm trying to mirror the environment so I tiried installing firefox in my other box like so:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox=41.0+build3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '41.0+build3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1' for 'firefox' was not found
```

Unfortuntaely it doesn't seem like it's able to find my specific version of firefox that I'm trying to install. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why not download Firefox 41 build from Firefox.com?

Comment: @xangua Yeah, I ended up opting for that option. :(